# Where could i start to try and make something like this video?

Tags: animation

i was browsing the web for some animated backgrounds for ppt when i came accross this:
http://www.faithclipart.com/video/he-is-the-vine-video-splash-screen-loop.html

Does anyone know what techniques, programs or whatever, is used to create something like this?

Cheers,
Randomman159

Answer (score 3):

Yes - definitely After Effects. This tutorial:

http://layersmagazine.com/animated-swirls-in-adobe-after-effects.html

will show you how to do it. You start by creating the vectors in Illustrator, then import them and animate them using the Stroke effect in After Effects.

I would warn you, however, that from a useability standpoint animated backgrounds for PowerPoint slides are usually a really, really bad idea - folks will be too busy watching your animation to pay attention to what you're presenting, so unless it's for a kiosk-style presentation you should really think hard before you use an animated background. Remember - the human eye evolved to track motion, so that's where it's going to go. You can use this to your advantage (animated reveals will draw the viewer's eye to the current bullet point) but it's easy for animations to become distracting.

Comment: Amen on the Powerpoint caveat! +1 for the link.

Comment: Speaking of After Effects, here's an example of how outrageous it can get. This is a second-ever video by a pretty new AE user, which makes it even more amazing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShhRE5P8Z7c&feature=player_embedded#at=61

Answer (score 1):

This was done with After Effects, almost certainly. It's a classic AE effect, often used in tutorials and demos, using animated masking. You could do the same thing in Flash, not as easily. You could even do this in Photoshop, but that would take great care and a long time.